# Generate a dynamic HTML id with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello I want to generate a unique identifier in html in the form 'a1' 'a2' according to the values ​​of the table I think to do like that

```
    <div ng-controller="ddController" >
            <div class="containerslot" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                    <div ng-repeat="r in [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]">
                        <span class="slot grey" id="{{'a'+r}}" ng-repeat="c in [1]" x-lvl-draggable='true' x-lvl-drop-target="true" x-on-drop="dropped(dragEl, dropEl)" ng-dblclick="showTabDialog(r)" data-color="grey"><button style="margin-right: 145px;
                            height: 22px;
                            display: block;" ng-click="openUserProfile(r)">config</button></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

when my javascript retrieves the id it retrieves {{'a' + r}} not the identifier exemple:

```
var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text"); //collect {{'a'+r}} not 'a1'
                var dest = document.getElementById(id);
                var src = document.getElementById(data);
```

I really don't see how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is "String Interpolation in AngularJS", to get your Ids looking like a1, a2, etc, change `id="{{'a'+r}}"` to `id="a{{r}}"`

EDIT:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LOch8g8q6FtrMZPV?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1 , it seems to me that your problem is wanting to perform DOM manipulations a bit too early? Look at developer tools while you are running the little code snippet. You should see the a1 element.

Comment: thanks for your answer i changed 
but my javascript always retrieves a{{r}} and not the values

Comment: Ah, I see! Check out this plunker @corsi : https://plnkr.co/edit/LOch8g8q6FtrMZPV?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1 , it seems to me that your problem is wanting to perform DOM manipulations a bit too early? Look at developer tools while you are running the little code snippet. You should see the a1 element.

Comment: @corsi, of interest to you will likely be this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: @corsi, sweet! Happy to hear it. If so, can you please mark it answered so I can collect that sweet karma? :)